# How can I make a row of checkboxes in html with all the labels centered above the checkboxes?

Tags: python, html, checkbox, label

I am trying to create a spreadsheet in html with checkboxes, but am having trouble formatting the labels to be centered above the checkboxes.

My current code has the labels to the right of the checkboxes like this:

```
Label []  Label []  Label []  Label []
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
Label    Label    Label    Label

 ....[.]........[.]........[.]........[.]
```

(Excuse the extraneous dots this is my first time posting a question here and it keeps messing up my formatting when I submit.)

Comment: please provide some code on hat is done so far:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li label {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="check1">Label</label><input type="checkbox" id="check1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="check2">Label</label><input type="checkbox" id="check2">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="check3">Label</label><input type="checkbox" id="check3">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="check4">Label</label><input type="checkbox" id="check4">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="check5">Label</label><input type="checkbox" id="check5">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know why when I try to center the entire thing on the page, the list of checkboxes becomes vertical instead of horizontal?

Comment: In that case your styles do not get applied, probably. You can use your browser’s inspect feature to see which CSS rules get applied.

Comment: Ok one more question Im sorry, I want these checkboxes to line up with the rows below them, but many of the checkboxes have different length labels. It seems that part of your code causes the checkboxes to space themselves out based on the label length, is there a way to stop that so all the checkboxes are evenly aligned?